# Repeat string with a specific pattern without slicing

Tags: python, string, loops, input, slice

I'm working on a pretty annoying Python assignment and I'm lost. These are the requirements:

- Ask for input.
- For each character in the saved string I need to output said string with a certain modification. For example, if the input is `abcd` the output looks like this:

```
abcd
bcda
cdab
dabc
```

I.e. there are `len(input)` lines, each line begins with the next `input[i]` character and repeats to the length of the original input.

- I should not use slicing, it's loop practice (T_T). No functions or packages. Loops only.

I made a working script that looks like this:

```
w = input('Type a word:')
w2 = ''

for i, char in enumerate(w):
    w2 = w[i:]+w[:i]
    print(w2)
```

It's neat and short. But it will be marked down for slicing. Can Python loop gurus please help me remake it into loops? Thanks so much in advance!

Comment: Please repeat [on topic](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) and [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) from the
[intro tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour).  
"Show me how to solve this coding problem?" is off-topic for Stack Overflow.
You have to make an honest attempt at the solution, and then ask a *specific* question about your implementation.
Stack Overflow is not intended to replace existing tutorials and documentation.

Comment: Also check [can someone help me?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/284236/why-is-can-someone-help-me-not-an-actual-question).  Avoid the off-topic areas given in this description, update your post, and you're *much* more likely to get help.  For instance, show your attempt to replace that slicing with a loop.

Comment: @Prune - The title is well-stated and has an attempted solution that doesn't work. I think it fits this site well.

Answer (score 2):

If you can't slice strings, you can append and pop lists. So, convert the string to a list and work with list methods.

```
>>> test = "abcd"
>>> l = list(test)
>>> for _ in range(len(l)):
...     print("".join(l))
...     l.append(l.pop(0))
... 
abcd
bcda
cdab
dabc
```

Comment: As it’s clearly an assigment, and the OP didn’t make any attempt to answer the question with the constraints they themselves cite, .. why answer? https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/334822/how-do-i-ask-and-answer-homework-questions Very disappointing.

Comment: Thank you, I haven't thought of converting to a list, also range() seems very appropriate for the task. Will try.

Comment: @barny - Because OP clearly met the standard. The problem was clearly stated. Even though there is a "will you help me" in the text, the title of the question is clear. OP attempted a solution, but it fails the constraint. OP was unsure how to approach the problem, so there wasn't a second solution. Quite a few bugs on this site are this way. Would you not answer a `pandas` question because the person doesn't know about a particular ufunc?

Comment: @CathNeman - When you don't use one of the values iterated by `enumerate` its a good indication it wasn't needed after all.

Comment: @barny I did attempt to use loops multiple times, but only the code I posted at least produces the required output, the other scripts were not even close. Sorry if my questing does not meet the standard, I mostly lurk here and rarely post.

Comment: @CathNeman - I thought your question was on-topic. Don't let this keep you from other questions!

Comment: @tdelaney I see the issue with `enumerate`, it was legacy from my other attempts to use loops. This is helpful!

Answer (score 2):

You can use indexing into the original string using a modulo on itself:

```
w = "aword" 
lw = len(w)

for offset in range(lw):
    for character in range(lw):
        print(w[(offset+character) % lw], end="")
    print()
```

Output:

```
aword
worda
ordaw
rdawo
dawor
```

If your sum of offset and character overshoots the amount of characters the modulo operation wraps it around.

Comment: As it’s clearly an assigment, and the OP didn’t make any attempt to answer the question with the constraints they themselves cite, .. why answer? https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/334822/how-do-i-ask-and-answer-homework-questions Very disappointing.

Comment: Thanks a lot, I forgot about range() for some reason.

Comment: @barny the method of using a modulo for indexing into the string is new, but the question proposed a solution to the problem with slicing. So I see an attempt of a solution, the question looks otherwise ok as well. Pulling this moduly indexing out of thin air might be asking a bit much, so why not answering? Considering the questions that normally occur here, this one gets a 3.5/5 star rating.

Answer (score -1):

Just for fun another one:

```
s = 'aword'
ss = s * 2  # 'awordaword'
for i in range(len(s)):
    for j in range(len(s)):
        print(ss[i+j], end='')
    print()
```

Output:

```
aword
worda
ordaw
rdawo
dawor
```